# Counting number of occurrences in column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

What would be a good approach to calculate the number of occurrences in a spreadsheet column? Can this be done with a single *array formula*?

Example (column `A` is *input*, columns `B` and `C` are *to be auto-generated*):

```
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
+-------+-------+-------+
| Name  | Name  | Count |
+-------+-------+-------+
| Joe   | Joe   |     2 |
| Lisa  | Lisa  |     3 |
| Jenny | Jenny |     2 |
| Lisa  |       |       |
| Lisa  |       |       |
| Joe   |       |       |
| Jenny |       |       |
```

Comment: Also You can use =ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(A2:A8,"=" & B2:B8)). This is a simple way.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(A:A&{"",""};"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Count'";1))`

---

22/07/2014 Some time in the last month, Sheets has started supporting more flexible concatenation of arrays, using an embedded array. So the solution may be shortened slightly to:

`=QUERY({A:A,A:A},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Count'",1)`

Comment: For me, A is a date. When grouping, that date is converted to an integer for the second column? How can I make sure column two has the same format as the first column (a date)?

Comment: How would this be changed to do the same for multiple columns?

Answer (score 120):

A simpler approach to this

At the beginning of column B, type

```
=UNIQUE(A:A)
```

Then in column C, use

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, B1)
```

and copy them in all row column C.

Edit: If that doesn't work for you, try using semicolon instead of comma:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A; B1)
```

Comment: I just checked it, and indeed this looks like an elegant solution! Still, I keep the answer by @AdamL as accepted for now, since it does everything in one line without the need to copy rows in column C.

Comment: I can't get this workig, can you see why? This is a sample spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HWdVTQAdWKbsdzO80MtYqwk1rNIGqnfqSk24hjNS3Wk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Somehow, in your spreadsheet you need to use semicolon instead of comma, i.e. =COUNTIF(B:B; C2). But I can use comma if I create a new spreadsheet myself. not sure why..

Answer (score 40):

```
=COUNTIF(A:A;"lisa")
```

You can replace the criteria with cell references from Column B

Comment: Read again: Column `B` is *to be auto-generated*.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding some extra sorting if needed

```
=QUERY(A2:A,"select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A order by count(A) DESC label A 'Name', count(A) 'Count'",-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(B2:B),iferror(1/0),mmult(sign(B2:B=TRANSPOSE(A2:A)),A2:A)))
```

I got this from a good tutorial - can't remember the title - probably about using MMult

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in B3 (credit to @Alexander-Ivanov for the countif condition):

```
={UNIQUE(A3:A),ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(UNIQUE(A3:A),"=" & UNIQUE(A3:A)))}
```

Benefits: It only requires editing 1 cell, it includes the name filtered by uniqueness, and it is concise.

Downside: it runs the unique function 3x

To use the unique function only once, split it into 2 cells:

B3: `=UNIQUE(A3:A)`

C3: `=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(B3:B,"=" & B3:B))`

Comment: The unique function for C3 should be =ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(A2:A,"=" & B2:B))