# Counting number of instances

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I have a list of items in google sheets and I want to generate a new sheet that provides a count by a sub-category. There can be an infinite number of items, and each can have an infinite number of sub-categories. I'm sure an answer of how to do it in Excel would guide me in the right direction too.

For the sake of simplicity let's pretend I have a list of individual gizmos and the color that they are piece by piece. I want to generate a new list that based on the that gives a total count of how many Blue wingdings there are, blue zingzongs, red wingdings, etc.... There could be any amount of colors or gizmos.

I'm looking for a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125847/counting-number-of-occurrences-in-column) but my problem is slightly more complicated.

Comment: Sounds like a pivot table?

Comment: That did it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim Williams, I was able to easily do this with a **pivot table.**