# Make Bar chart from single column of Spreadsheet data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have a big spreadsheet with a column of categorized data. I want to create a bar chart for each column representing the count of the different values in that column. I tried to automate this process with Google Apps Script, but the result I get is quite wrong.

Here is the code I am using

```js
function myFunction() {

var responseSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://mySpreadsheetLink")
                          .getActiveSheet();
Logger.log(responseSpreadSheet.getName());

var titles = responseSpreadSheet.getRange(1, 4, 1, 25).getValues(); 

var barChart = responseSpreadSheet.newChart()
               .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
               .setOption('title', titles[0][0])
               .addRange(responseSpreadSheet.getRange("D2:D57"))
               .setPosition(5, 5, 0,0)
               .build();


responseSpreadSheet.insertChart(barChart);
}
```

Here is the spreadsheet with the embedded bar chart:

[image: embedded bar chart]

And the desired outcome will be this

[image: desired outcome]

How do I create this type of chart over my column?

Answer (score 7):

EmbeddedCharts do not expose all the capabilities available to Spreadsheet Charts, nor all the features of the Visualization API. The specific limitations you're up against here:

- EmbeddedCharts only use spreadsheet Ranges for data sources.
- The automatic Aggregation settings supported in the Sheets UI are not available programmatically.

  The desired chart isn't simply graphing a single column of data, it's effectively generating a table from it through Aggregation. When you select a single column of text cells, the default chart will be bar chart titled "Count of [column header]", with "Aggregate column" enabled, like this:

  [image: settings]

#### How to get the same results via script

Let's say Column A consists of a list of respondents' favourite pets:

```
Favourite Pet
-------------
Cat
Cat
Dog
Alpaca
Budgie
Budgie
Cat
Dog
Hamster
Cat
Gerbil
Rabbit
Dog
Rabbit
Cat
Dog
```

The sum-aggregate data would look like:

```
Favourite Pet   Count
---------------------
Cat               5
Dog               4
Alpaca            1
Budgie            2
Hamster           1
Gerbil            1
Rabbit            2
```

### Option 1: Spreadsheet functions

Because of the limitations of EmbeddedCharts, the data to be displayed must be in a "Table", a Range or set of Ranges, so you need to meet that requirement. One way would be to use a Sheets `QUERY()` function, as in [Counting number of occurrences in column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125847/counting-number-of-occurrences-in-column/12233619#12233619):

```
=QUERY({A:A,A:A},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Count'",1)
```

To insert a chart programmatically, use the range produced by the above `QUERY` in your existing script.

### Option 2: All by Script

The script needs to generate a similar table of aggregate data. There are numerous examples of that in JavaScript, such as [Counting the occurrences of JavaScript array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-of-javascript-array-elements). With that, and an array transposing function from [Google Spreadsheet Script - How to Transpose / Rotate Multi-dimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621470/google-spreadsheet-script-how-to-transpose-rotate-multi-dimensional-array/16705104#16705104), we can put that together like this:

```
/**
 * Generate a table with summed categories (counts).
 *
 * @param {Object[][]} data   Single column of values to be counted.
 *
 * @returns {Object[][]}      Two columns, categories and counts
 */
function sumAggregate( data ) {
  // transpose spreadsheet column; we want just column 0.
  var arr = transpose( data )[0];

  // Magically aggregate array items. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/28832203/1677912
  var agg = arr.reduce(function(countMap, word) {countMap[word] = ++countMap[word] || 1;return countMap}, {});

  // Convert aggregated data into a 2-D array
  var result = [];
  for (var item in agg) {
    result.push( [item,agg[item]] );
  }
  return result;
}

// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/16705104/1677912
function transpose(a)
{
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}
```

With that function taking care of generating the table of sums required for the chart, we just need to generate the data and place it into the spreadsheet.

```
function generateChart() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  var options = chart.getOptions();
  var a = JSON.stringify(options.get('width'))

  var data = sheet.getRange("A1:A17").getValues();
  var header = data.splice(0, 1);                // remove header row
  var aggregateData = sumAggregate( data );
  aggregateData.unshift([header[0][0],"Count"]); // replace & expand header row

  // Store in spreadsheet
  var tableRange = sheet.getRange(1, 3, aggregateData.length, aggregateData[0].length);
  tableRange.setValues(aggregateData);

  var barChart = sheet.newChart()
               .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
               .setOption('title', 'Count of '+header[0][0])
               .setPosition(5, 5, 0,0)
               .addRange(tableRange)
               .build();

  sheet.insertChart(barChart);  
}
```

### Result:

[image: screenshot]